# Solution to a System of Autonomous Linear Differential Equations with an Extra Constant

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am dealing with a system of **four** differential equations.

Here they are:

$$v'=Ax+Bh+C$$
$$w'=Dh+Fx$$
$$h'=w$$
$$x'=v$$

where x, v, h, w are all variables and A, B, C, D, F are all constants. I know from basic Diff Eq that this could be solved easily if the $-C$ term wasn't there using the eigenvalue method. Any suggestions as to how to solve (or if this can even be solved)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although there are four differential equations, one can view it as a single, first order linear differential equation on $\mathbb{R}^4.$ Set $z := (h, x, w, v)$ and observe that,

$$
z'(t) = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\ D & F & 0 & 0\\ B & A & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\,z(t) + \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ C \end{pmatrix}.
$$

Assuming you wish to solve an initial value problem, i.e. $z(0)= z_0$ is known, then there is a way to compute the solution to the ODE. Let,

$$\mathbf{A} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\ D & F & 0 & 0\\ B & A & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix},\qquad
\mathbf{B} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ C \end{pmatrix},
$$
so our ODE can be concisely written as,

$$z'(t) = \mathbf{A}\,z(t) + \mathbf{B}.$$

It can be verified by direct computation that the solution to the initial value problem is,

$$
z(t) 
=
\exp(\mathbf{A} t)\,z_0 + \int_{0}^{t} \exp\left(\mathbf{A}(t - \tau)\right)\,\mathbf{B}\,d\tau,$$

where $\exp$ is the matrix exponential.
It is often easier to first resolve the expression in the Laplace domain,

$$Z(s) = (s I - \mathbf{A})^{-1}\,z_0 + (s I - \mathbf{A})^{-1}\,\frac{\mathbf{B}}{s},$$

perform term-by-term partial fraction expansion and use a look-up table to invert the terms; symbolic toolboxes churn through these problems quite happily. Either way, you can directly compute the answer given specific numbers for your parameters. This is because these parameters determine the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{A}$ which in turn determine the types of functions that pop out of the matrix exponential. This approach generalizes to even when the affine term is an arbitrary (known) signal $C(t)$ that is sufficiently well-behaved.

Comment: Or, one can eliminate the constant term via the change of variables $z = u - A^{-1}B$, to yield $u' = Au$.

Comment: @JohnBarber When $\mathbf{A}$ is invertible, yes